# AWS RDS VPC Security

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

Could someone confirm on the security benefits if any of the following:

> I have an Internet facing Web Server in a VPC, this is peered to
>   another VPC running an application firewall.
>
> The Web Server will talk to an RDS instance which will only be accessible by the application and a
>   management server (for support purposes, hosted in another VPC).

The question is - Should the RDS instance be placed on the same VPC as the Webserver or hosted in a separate VPC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is totally up to you! In general, you should minimise the complexity unless there is a reason.

Putting a database in a separate VPC is definitely overkill. Sometimes people put the database in a **private subnet** to add an additional layer of security.

You should certainly configure the **security groups** like this:

- A Web Server security group (`Web-SG`) associated with the Web Server that permits desired traffic (eg HTTP, HTTPS) from the Internet (`0.0.0.0/0`)
- A Database Security group (`DB-SG`) associated with the RDS instance that permits inbound traffic on the desired port from `Web-SG`

That is, `DB-SG` permits inbound access from `Web-SG` by referring to `Web-SG` specifically (instead of by IP address). This means that any EC2 instance associated with `Web-SG` will be permitted access to the database.